# Disable magnifying glass of UITextView But enable the Link and phone number detection in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator

I have an issue with UITextview in iOS9, when i do a longpress on textview it shows the magnifying glass. I tried to disable through UILongPressGestureRecognizer, it completely disables the Link and phone touch events also.

How to Disable only Magnifing glass.
the textview will be in a UITableView cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to disable magnifying glass but it was system called.you can only do only was that change `UIMenuController state:hidden` or `show` and the `UIMenuItem` within `UIMenuController`. like  this

[image]

Comment: No........ Menu is working fine but i am not able disable the magnifying glass.....

Answer (score 0):

[image]UILongPressGestureRecognizer uncheck cancels touches in view if using stroyboard and if doing it from code set its value to false

Comment: I stil found a problem by setting the property to false . Magnifying glass still come. If i disabled the UILongPressGestureRecognizer then  it disable the phone number and link detection .

Comment: I got my answer... I just reduce the delay amount of UILongPressGesture. It solve my problem. Thanks for all for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

check  DetectLinks
uncheck Selectable, Editable
[image: screenshot UITextView settings]

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed this for myself. In your UITextView subclass, use:

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // remove magnifying glass, still allowing link detection:
    if ([gestureRecognizer class] == [UILongPressGestureRecognizer class] || [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // remove magnifying glass, still allowing link detection:
    if ([gestureRecognizer class] == [UILongPressGestureRecognizer class] || [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass and override gesture for only tap gesture implementation. It will also disable multiple single tap gesture UITextTapGestureRecognizer which is private. You dont want multiple clicks anyway I guess.

```
override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) {
        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self) { return true }
    return false
}
```